# How to search for a string only in textfiles? (recursively)

Tags: find, grep

I can list all the textfiles (by mimetype) in a folder with:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file -i | fgrep -i text | sed 's/:$//g' 2>/dev/null | awk 'BEGIN {FS=": "} {print $1}'
```

Ok. But how can I add "fgrep" to this, to search in these files for "STRING" (regexp not needed, that's why fgrep).

this isn't good:

```
fgrep -iR "STRING" *
```

because it starts to search in ISO files, binary files too...

Fedora14/bash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***First***, the `grep`: You can tell it not to search through binary files - use the `-I` switch - as manpage says:

> ```
> -I     Process a binary  file  as  if  it  did  not  contain  matching data;
>        this  is  equivalent  to  the --binary-files=without-match option.
> ```

---

***Second***, the `find`: To avoid using xargs and lots of piping, make use of the `-exec` test of `find` program. You can easily create a chain of logical tests using this: each consecutive `-exec` is performed *if* all the previous commands returned 0 (finished successfully).

Comment: What would be the final (correct and complete) command?

Answer (score 0):

That of @rozcietrzewiacz is a great solution, but if you still want to stay with text files (as returned by `file`), you can carefully build an array of file names, then execute your `grep` command on that array.

I suppose the following:

- in no filename there is a newline (but spaces can be present);
- a `file` util that support `-0` and `-i` options;
- GNU sed, or a sed supporting `\x` exadecimal char codes.

Here is an example

```
#!/bin/bash

get_file_list() {
  local path="$1"
  find "$path" -type f -exec file -0i {} + |
    sed -n '/\x00  *text\//s/\x00.*//p'
}

list=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
  list+=("$line")
done < <(get_file_list .)

# to choose options and pattern
grep -i pattern "${list[@]}"
```

The `sed` command take a sequence of line of text coming from `file`, composed from a filename, a NUL byte and the mime-type. If in the second part (after the NUL) there is the word `text/` then remove that part and only print the filename, otherwise print nothing.