# Linux - How do I search all non-binary (text) files recursively for a certain string

Tags: bash, find

Linux - How do I search all non-binary (text) files recursively for a certain string

- search all files for a string
- skip binary
- recursively
- list filenames
- (and if possible echo the line + line number of the filename where it was found as option)

I was looking at 
[Bash: passing braces as arguments to bash function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57102/bash-passing-braces-as-arguments-to-bash-function/57197#57197)
and [How to search for a string only in textfiles? (recursively)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18719/how-to-search-for-a-string-only-in-textfiles-recursively)

But did not find an answer, only discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, adding the following options:

- `-F` or `--fixed-strings`
- `-I` or `--binary-files=without-match`
- `-r` or `--recursive`
- this is the default when using `-r`, but may be made explicit with `-H` or `--with-filename`
- `-n` or `--line-number`

So

```
grep -FIrn string .
```

See `man grep`.